# How do I change the content on my website based on subdomains all pointing to the ASPX same server?

Tags: dns, subdomain, language, web.config, aspx

I have created multiple subdomains on my DNS (`en.example.com` / `pt.example.com` / `ru.example.com`), all related to languages and all pointed to the same IP address.

I want to get the information from the prefix (`en`/`pt`/`ru`) and interpret in the back end of my website to get the language. Is it possible? And how can I do it?
(I'm using Aspx in visual studio)

Comment: This is more of a programming question, so more on topic of [so]. Yes what you want to do is possible in any language, any HTTP server and framework/library below it has access to all parts of the request, including the hostname. Before asking a  question on [so] about this you should first need to search a little for similar questions and see what you have attempted to do already as people will not write code for you.